# Cannot delete file upload

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am beginner with node.js and mongodb..I try to learn file upload tutorial..It show how to upload and download the file.. So i try to also include delete function to delete the file but it is not working..Can someone please show me how to fix it? Thank you.

This is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
         cb(null,'./public/uploads')
    },
    filename(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage});

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/files',{useNewUrlParser:false})
 .then(()=>console.log('connect')).catch(err=>console.log(err))


const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    filespath:String
})


 const fileModel = mongoose.model('filesdemo',fileSchema)


app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.set("views",path.resolve(__dirname,'views'));

const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'public');

app.use(express.static(filePath));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    fileModel.find((err,data)=>{
             if(err){
                 console.log(err)
             }
            if(data){
                console.log(data)
                res.render('home',{data:data})
            } 
           else{
               res.render('home',{data:{}})
           } 
    })
    
})

app.post('/',upload.single('file'),(req,res)=>{
    const x= 'uploads/'+req.file.originalname;
    const files = new fileModel({
        filespath:x
    })
    files.save((err,data)=>{
         if(err){
             console.log(err)
         }
         else{
             console.log('data',data)
            res.redirect('/')
         }
    })
})

app.get('/download/:id',(req,res)=>{
     fileModel.find({_id:req.params.id},(err,data)=>{
         if(err){
             console.log(err)
         } 
         else{
            const path= __dirname+'/public/'+data[0].filespath;
            res.download(path);
         }
     })
})

app.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    fileModel.find({_id: req.params.id}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            const path= __dirname+'/public/'+data[0].filespath;
            fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(path + ' was deleted');
            });

            fileModel.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('File deleted successfully');
                    res.send('File deleted successfully');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;
app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`server running at ${port}`))

module.exports = app;
```

This is my home.ejs

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     
     <center>
        <h2>Upload Files</h2>
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="file"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form><br><br><br><br>
    </center>
    <h2>Download Files</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        image
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        download
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% for(var i=0; i < data.length > 0; i++) {%>
                 <tr>
                     <td><img src="<%= data[i].filespath %>" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></td>
                     <td>
                         <form action="/download/<%= data[i]._id %>" method="GET">
                          <input type="submit" value="Download">
                        </form>
                        <form action="/delete/<%= data[i]._id %>" method="GET">
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                          </form>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                <% } %>

            
            </tbody>
        </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I use `"body-parser": "^1.20.1", "ejs": "^3.1.8", "express": "^4.18.2", "mongoose": "^6.8.1", "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"`

Solving delete file not functioning..I hope someone can teach me what did I do wrong.

Comment: Can you share the error you are facing while deleting the file.

Comment: @Shamoon97 i get this error when I try to delete the file. Cannot GET /delete/63c4eb03ad326f0659723711

Comment: I think you are sending get request instead of the delete request. That is why it is saying cannot GET. Please verify it.

Comment: Change it to app.get and it work as it display delete successfully but when try to return app crash..need to restart nodemon again and it delete the file that I want to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `const fs = require('fs')` and change your `/delete` endpoint to :

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    fileModel.find({_id: req.params.id}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            const path= __dirname+'/public/'+data[0].filespath;
            fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(path + ' was deleted');
            });

            fileModel.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('File deleted successfully');
                    res.send('File deleted successfully');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It work after i change it to app.post.. It goes to another page and said file deletd succesfully, then I try to return the file still no delete..after clicking delete two or three time, it crash.. Need to restart nodemon again and reload the page..Now it delete the file that I want..How can fix this? Instead of it show another page, file deleted successfully, it would be better it can delete the file in the same page in file upload..So it would not crash..Do you have any suggestion?